# Way to find incremental changes in the system

Tags: java, postgresql

We have a Java based system with postgres as database. For some reasons we want to propagate certain changes on timely basis (say 1 hour) to a different location. The two broad approaches are

- Logging all the changes to a file as and when that happens. However
  this approach will scatter the code everywhere.
- Somehow find the incremental changes in postgres between two time stamps in
     some log files and send that. However I am not sure how feasible is this 
     approach.

Anyone has any thoughts/ideas around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the database size is not very great, you could do it quick&dirt by just:

- Dumping the entire postgresql to a textfile.
- (If the dump file is not sorted *1) sorting the textfile.
- Create a diff file with the previous dump file.

Of course, I would only advice this for a situation where your database is going to be kept relatively small and you are just going to use it for a couple of servers.

*1: I do not know if it is somehow sorted, check the docs.

Comment: You'd have to dump table-by-table and then sort each table. If you sort the whole dump you'll just get garbage as tables are cross-sorted into each other. You're much better off using `COPY` to dump the tables in sorted form using `COPY (SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY the_primary_key) TO '/path/to/dump_thetable'` and diffing them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options available:

- Depending on the amount of data being written you could give [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/) a try.
- Otherwise it is also possible to do something with [PgQ](http://skytools.projects.postgresql.org/doc/pgq-sql.html) in combination with [Londiste](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Londiste_Tutorial)
- Or create something yourself by using triggers so you can generate some kind of audit table

Answer (score 1):

There are many pre-packaged approaches, so you probably don't need to develop your own.  Many of the options are summarized and compared on this Wiki page:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Many of them are based on the use of triggers to capture the data, with automatic generation of the triggers based on a more user-friendly interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own solution, I would advise to leverage work already done by others.  And in the case you described I would go for PgQ + Londiste (both part of Skytools package), that are easy to set up and use.  If you do not want streaming replication, you could still use PgQ / Londiste to easily capture DMLs and write them to a file that you can load when needed.  This would allow you expand your setup / processing when new requirements come.